# Passing product attributes to PayPal line items

Tags: magento-1.7, attributes, paypal

With PayPal "Transfer cart line items" set to Yes, is there a way to also transfer some of product attributes?

I've had a look at Paypal/Model/Api and [Payment Details Item Type Fields](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoExpressCheckoutPayment_API_Operation_NVP/), but Paypal extension's internal cart only seems to be storing only title, qty and amount.

I also tried to test with `paypal_prepare_line_items` event. Interestingly enough, the whole thing would crash without an error each time I try to var_dump or in any way read content of $observer->getPaypalCart() in the observer method. I haven't been able to move from there.

I was wondering if anyone's had luck adding product attributes to Paypal line items.

Answer (score 1):

Without any real information from the 'crash' you receive from the Paypal transfer line items event we can't really provide actual support. However, this is how I would do it:

```
<?php

class YourCompany_YourModule_Model_Observer
{
    public function addAttributeToPaypalItem(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $paypalCart = $observer->getEvent()->getPaypalCart();

        if(!$paypalCart){
            return;
        } elseif(!$paypalCart->getSalesEntity() instanceof Mage_Sales_Model_Quote) {
            return;
        }

        //loop through all paypal cart items
        foreach($paypalCart->getAllItems() as $item){
            //loop through all quote items
            foreach($paypalCart->getSalesEntity()->getAllItems() as $quoteItem){
                //if we have a match of quote items and paypal items, update paypal item name
                if($quoteItem->getSku()==$item->getId()){
                    $item->setName($item->getName() . ' ' . $quoteItem->getYourAttributeCodeHere());
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

What the above does is loop through all items in the quote and all items in the paypal 'cart' and when it finds a match it changes the name of the product in the Paypal cart to append a custom attribute of your choice.

HTH. Cheers.

Comment: FWIW I don't like nested loops - but it's good enough for gov't work for the sake of this question.