# Does Magento send the order increment_id to paypal?

Tags: magento-1.7, orders, paypal, transaction

I'm interrested in matching orders paid with PayPal by their increment id.

Therefore I want to use a summary (from PayPal) of orders and compare it with a list of the increment ids provided by the magento backend.

Currently I'm doing this by opening the transactions panel in the backend and match the transaction numbers. Is there a option doing this the way described above?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes If you are using Magento's Paypal standard module then the increment_id is sent over to Paypal and here is the proof:

[image: screen-shot]

Comment: oh.. yes, we thought about the default extension, thx :-*

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is possible with some of the explained [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4175/passing-product-attributes-to-paypal-line-items).
You can use the `paypal_prepare_line_items` event and create an Observer to add some more info.
There are 2 other events for PayPal, im not sure if they will fit better. Check them [here.](http://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-7/)

Comment: hm... this way I'd add the order increment id to every item

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think Magento pass the increment id into Paypal. If you look at transaction detail in your Paypal page, you can see that increment id. 
But I do not really understand what you are trying to do. Can you be more specific? I may assist you with this.

Comment: well currently we've no access to such a paypal inside view. if you could provide me a more convincing fact (more than _I think ..._) I'd be happy ;-)