# Can I specify the order details included in PayPal Express Checkout payment confirmation?

Tags: paypal-express

I am using PayPal Express Checkout on my Magento 2 site. The payment confirmation emails contain a description (configurable product name only), quantity, and amount. At a minimum, I would like these emails to also contain the other attributes such as size, etc, or possibly the sku since those attributes are contained in my skus. Is there a way to get these attributes into the PayPal payment confirmation email? This would be more convenient for us than using the pdf invoice for order picking.

I found a hint on how to do this in an old answer to another [question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4175/passing-product-attributes-to-paypal-line-items) that probably applies to Magento 1. Not sure how applicable it is to the current code.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to write a plugin that edits product name before send product info to paypal.